# How to dynamically find the IP of a host in a Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I need to find the IP of a node, if there is one. The problem is that 'cluster_nodes.first' is OK but it does not have any method, '.ip' does not exists, cluster_nodes.first[:ip] either and I cannot find any information on the Chef Wiki.

```
cluster_nodes = search(:node, "name:cluster1*")

if cluster_nodes.size > 0
  node[:primary_node] = cluster_nodes.first.ip
else
  node[:primary_node] = ''
end
```

Error:

```
[Sat, 01 Sep 2012 10:29:22 +0000] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Sat, 01 Sep 2012 10:29:22 +0000] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
[Sat, 01 Sep 2012 10:29:22 +0000] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Sat, 01 Sep 2012 10:29:22 +0000] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[Sat, 01 Sep 2012 10:29:22 +0000] FATAL: ArgumentError: Attribute ip is not defined!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haproxy recipe it has a good example and this is a snippet taken from that recipe:

```
cluster_nodes = search(:node, "name:cluster1*")
member = cluster_nodes.first if cluster_nodes

if cluster_nodes && cluster_nodes.size > 0
  primary_node = begin
    if member.attribute?('cloud')
      if node.attribute?('cloud') && (member['cloud']['provider'] == node['cloud']['provider'])
         member['cloud']['local_ipv4']
      else
        member['cloud']['public_ipv4']
      end
    else
      member['ipaddress']
    end
  end
else
  primary_node = ''
end
```

It works for me. the first node gets an empty value, the second, third and so on get the IP address.